# Integrate jacoco code coverage reports from Azure devops to Code climate

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, jacoco, code-climate

We are using Azure devops to run our build and jacoco to do code coverage in azure build agent. We want to integrate code coverage reports to code climate.

Has anyone tried it ? I tried searching for proper documentation or steps and it seems to be missing.

Any help/pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , as far as I know there should be no way to integrate jacoco code coverage reports from Azure devops to Code climate directly . After all, there is already a code coverage feature on azure devops, why integrate code coverage reports into Code climate.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.

A manual method I can think of is to download the code coverage results , then open it in vs and then push it into the repo of the code climate. Because I am not very familiar with code climate, I am not sure about the feasibility of this idea.

[image]

Comment: I tried integrating the reports using reporter tool prebuilt binary and it worked. Steps are documented here.

https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/configuring-test-coverage

However, i had to create a task in azure-pipeline to run the test reporter by pointing it to respective ReportID

Comment: @user1768610 Sorry for the late reply,you can share your solution as an answer here.This will help users with the same issue.